# Correct or Incorrect? "Iterate on"

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I came across a sentence that uses 'iterate on'. Is this usage correct?

> "Unpack customer insights, and iterate on the content and the overall
>   design to produce innovative products and features."

Comment: It's a bit "techie", but perfectly legit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cambridge dictionary says to iterate is to repeat a process.

The common usage these days is in a computer program where a repeating loop uses an increasing (or decreasing) value to *iterate* on, or repeat, until a result is reached. The sentence given above describes this process using the user's insights to repeatedly focus or *iterate* on the needed content and the overall design.

The Cambridge use shows that the form of the sentence given is correct.